# How to get ultra private whois information like the following:

Tags: whois

How would i get ultra private DNS whois informaation like the following:

[link](http://who.is/whois/complaintsboard.com)

[link 2](https://snag.gy/Qz7wPH.jpg)

As you can see it is not just private domain registration, the nameservers on the two different whois sites are showing different information and it is very limited.

Many thanks,

Comment: If you are trying to do a whois look-up and get the protected/private whois data, that is not possible. There are things that can be done, however, you would have needed to have already done them.

Comment: Please add all the contents in your question, not through external links that can change. Explain what "ultra private" means to you and what is really your aim.

Comment: whois is not the authoritative source to find the nameservers of a domain, the DNS is.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ultra private. The information on one of the whois service (snaggy) is stale. Snaggy is showing old data and hence the difference.

I've checked with some other whois services and it is same. It is standard privacy guard offered by almost all registrars.

Comment: "old data" - "Last update of whois database: 21 Nov 2014"